# Why my variadic vsscanf function has undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, scanf

I created a variadic function to parse strings which might have different arguments.
In current case, the incoming string would be "38400,8,N,1\n".

```
static int parse_response(const char *buff, char *format, ...){
    
    uint16_t retval=0;
    va_list arg_ptr;
    va_start(arg_ptr, format);

    retval = vsscanf((const char*)buff, format, arg_ptr);
    va_end(arg_ptr);
    return retval;
}
```

here is the function where I called my vsscanf function.

```
 satel_return_typedef Satel_GetBaudrate(satel_typedef* Satel, uint32_t* Baudrate, uint32_t timeout_ms){
    
    int Len;
    Len = printf_SLCommandString(Satel->tx_data_buffer, Satel->max_size, "SL%%B?");
    uint8_t DataBits; char Parity; uint8_t StopBit;
    if(Len < 0 || Len > (int)Satel->max_size) {
        return R_API_ERROR;
    }
    if(Satel->Platform->Comm_Send(Satel->tx_data_buffer, Len, NULL)<0)
    return R_PLATFORM_ERROR;
    if(Satel_WaitForCommResponse(Satel,timeout_ms)==R_COMM_RESPONSE_VALUE){
        parse_response((char*)Satel->rx_data_buffer,"%d,%d,%c,%d\n", Baudrate, &DataBits, &Parity, &StopBit);
        return R_OP_SUCCESSED;
    }     
    return R_OP_ERROR;
}
```

I know, there are some rules to not fall into undefined behaviour but, My mind confused about which rules are breaking here.

```
typedef void (*Write_Enamod_Pin)(satel_power_typedef Config);
typedef void (*Write_Service_Pin)(satel_service_typedef Config);
typedef int32_t (*Send_Message)(const uint8_t *data_to_send, uint32_t bytes_to_send, void *custom); /* -1 IO Error*/
typedef int32_t (*Read_Message)(uint8_t *data_to_read, uint32_t bytes_to_read, void *custom); /* -1 IO Error*/
typedef uint32_t (*Get_TickCount)(void);
typedef void (*Delay_ms)(uint32_t milisec);
typedef struct{
    Write_Enamod_Pin    Power;
    Write_Service_Pin   Service;
    Send_Message        Comm_Send;
    Read_Message        Comm_Read;
    Get_TickCount       Get_TickCount;
    Delay_ms            Delay_Ms;
}satel_hw_typedef;
typedef struct{
    satel_state_typedef State;
    uint8_t*            tx_data_buffer;
    uint8_t*            rx_data_buffer;
    uint32_t            max_size;
    satel_hw_typedef*   Platform;
}satel_typedef;
```

Comment: Why not just use `sscanf`? You will get a helpful compiler warning if you try to misuse it.

Comment: Aside: Rathe than `Len > (int)Satel->max_size`, use `(unsigned)Len > Satel->max_size` for a full range compare.

Comment: @EmbeddedMaker,  Post definition of `satel_typedef` to improve the question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I updated.

Comment: @n.m.5 string size are unknown, arguments that is listed in the strings would be different that's why I wanted to do it with variadic function.

Comment: Your function has exactly the same interface as `sscanf` and does exactly the same thing `sscanf` does, not one bit more or less.

Comment: @n.m. you are correct and I think I mixed the consepts and I changed from variadic to sscanf.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a mismatch of format specifiers.

The `%d` format specifier expect an `int *`.  In the 3 places you're using it, you're passing a `uint32_t *`, a `uint8_t *`, and a `uint8_t *`.  Those mismatches trigger undefined behavior.

You need to use `u` for an unsigned integer argument for all 3, and you want to use the `hh` modifier for the `uint8_t` (i.e. `unsigned char`) arguments.  Also, you want to remove `\n` from the format string as that prevents reading from stopping until you press some other non-whitespace character *after* pressing ENTER.

```
"%u,%hhu,%c,%hhu"
```

Comment: Better than using %hhu and %u for uint8_t and uint32_t respectively, OP should probably use PRIu8 and PRIu32. Those choose the correct format specifiers for the compiled platform.

Comment: @dbush I tried but still not working.

Comment: @SafelyFast I changed formatters but nothing changed.

Comment: @SafelyFast:  the `PRI` format specifiers are for printf -- you want `SCN` ones for scanf -- so the format should be `"%"SCNu32",%"SCNu8",%c,%"SCNu8`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Good point. I misread the post.